# Using DFSORT: Input Signed Packed Fields converted to OUTREC Zone Decimal Fields with Sign + or -?

Tags: excel, dfsort

I have datasets that contain multiple packed signed values. I want to convert those fields to Zoned Decimal (Display) for reporting those values in an EXCEL Spreadsheet.

I have the non-signed packed field displaying ok, but the signed negative value does not show a `-`, i.e. `123D` ==> `-123`

Here's some DFSORT SYSIN:

```
OPTION COPY                                        
     OUTREC FIELDS=(001:001,004,PD,TO=FS,LENGTH=6,C'|',
            008:005,004,PD,EDIT=(STTT,TTT.TT)

Input:02460001 (2 fields) Output: 123456|S000,000.01
    135F000D
```

the `S` should be a `-`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of negative sign, I added `SIGNS=(,-)`. I added `SIGNS=(+,-)` for both signs.

```
OUTREC FIELDS=(001:001,004,PD,TO=FS,LENGTH=6,C'|',          
       008:005,004,PD,EDIT=(STTT,TTT.TT),SIGNS=(+,-)
```